# How to solve boundary condition?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$\begin{align}\frac{d^4 y}{dx^4}&-y=0\\y(0)&=1,\; y'(0)=1\\y(1)&=1,\;y'(1)=1\end{align}$$

I get $$y(x)=Ae^x+Be^{-x}+C\cos(x)+D\sin(x)$$

After applying conditions
$$\begin{align}1&=A+B+C\\1&=A-B+D\\1&=Ae+Be^{-1}+C\cos(1)+D\sin(1)\\1&=Ae-Be^{-1}-C\cos(1)+D\sin(1)\end{align}$$

How to solve it for A,B,C and D?

Every time I solve it I got mixed $A$, $B$, $C$ and $D$ not individual value of any one.

Comment: every time i solve i got mixed A,B,C and D not individual value of any one

Comment: A hint: If you write $y$ as $y(x) = \alpha \cosh x + \beta \sinh x + \gamma \cos x + \delta \sin x$, then the two conditions for $y(0)$ and $y'(0)$ are very nice and simple. Then the conditions at $1$ give you a system of two linear equations in two unknowns. That is then easier to solve.